# Python re returning non-matching lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to solve a regular expression puzzle and I'm ... puzzled. I expect the following:

```
import re
import fileinput

TEST_DATA = [
    "6",
    "2 ",
    "1 877 2638277 ",
    "91-011-23413627"
]

for line in TEST_DATA:
    print(
        re.sub(
            r'(\d{1,3})[- ](\d{2,3})[- ]+(\d{5,10})',
            r'CountryCode=\1,LocalAreaCode=\2,Number=\3',
            line))
```

to give me this:

```
CountryCode=1,LocalAreaCode=877,Number=2638277 
CountryCode=91,LocalAreaCode=011,Number=23413627
```

instead I get this:

```
6
2 
CountryCode=1,LocalAreaCode=877,Number=2638277 
CountryCode=91,LocalAreaCode=011,Number=23413627
```

I don't understand why the lines that don't match are being printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`re.sub` returns the string regardless of whether a replacement occurred. From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.sub):

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged.

Perhaps you could first check to see if a [match](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.match) occurred, and then perform the replacement.

```
for line in TEST_DATA:
    if re.match(my_pattern, line):
        print(
            re.sub(
                r'(\d{1,3})[- ](\d{2,3})[- ]+(\d{5,10})',
                r'CountryCode=\1,LocalAreaCode=\2,Number=\3',
                line))
```

Answer (score 2):

I gotta tell ya, I really HATE `re.sub`. I don't know why, I don't have a great explanation, but I avoid it like the plague. I can't even really remember ever using it to poor effect, I just don't like it....

The reason it's not producing your expected output is that `re.sub` will return the string regardless of whether it matches the regex. It's kind of like `"Hello there".replace("foo","bar")` -- just because it doesn't find anything to replace doesn't mean it throws away your string. What I would do instead is this:

```
pattern = r'(?P<country>\d{1,3})[- ](?P<area>\d{2,3})[- ]+(?P<number>\d{5,10})'
text = r"CountryCode={country},LocalAreaCode={area},number={number}"

for line in TEST_DATA:
    match = re.match(pattern,line)
    if not match: continue
    print(text.format(**match.groupdict()))
```

Comment: I suppose a closer reading of the documentation would have told me that it just returns the string if it doesn't match, but that seems like a reason to hate it.

Comment: @Amanda I don't need much of a reason, mind you! I also avoid regex like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
import re    

TEST_DATA = [
    "6",
    "2 ",
    "1 877 2638277 ",
    "91-011-23413627"
]

pattern = r'(\d{1,3})[- ](\d{2,3})[- ]+(\d{5,10})'
rep = r'CountryCode=\1,LocalAreaCode=\2,Number=\3'

for line in TEST_DATA:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        print re.sub(pattern,rep,line)
```